# JButton - No Click Anmation

Tags: java, animation, jframe, jbutton

i read some contributions about this but nothing helped.
I try to make a little application with a gui,
but the problem is, if i click the button, no animation appears and nothing happens. I hope you can help me.
That's the code:

```
public class StartFrame extends JFrame{

JTextField eingabe;
JLabel inhalt;
JButton button;
JCheckBox fett;
JCheckBox kursiv;
JCheckBox groß;
JPanel panel;

StartFrame(int sizeWidth, int sizeHeight, String title){

setSize(sizeWidth, sizeHeight);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setTitle(title);
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
setLayout(null);

inhalt = new JLabel("TeXt");
inhalt.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 60);
Font font = inhalt.getFont().deriveFont(Font.ITALIC, 15);
inhalt.setFont(font);
inhalt.setToolTipText("Das ist ein Text");
add(inhalt);

button = new JButton("HIER");
button.setBounds(100, 10, 100, 50);
button.addActionListener(new ClickListener());
button.setEnabled(false);
add(button);

eingabe = new JTextField();
eingabe.setBounds(300, 50, 150, 25);
eingabe.addCaretListener(new SchreibkopfListener());
add(eingabe);

panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(null);
panel.setBounds(10, 200, 150, 100);
add(panel);

fett = new JCheckBox("Fett");
fett.setBounds(0, 0, 150, 25);
fett.addItemListener(new FettListener());
panel.add(fett);

kursiv = new JCheckBox("Kursiv");
kursiv.setBounds(0, 25, 150, 25);
panel.add(kursiv);

groß = new JCheckBox("Groß");
groß.setBounds(0, 50, 150, 25);
panel.add(groß);

setVisible(true);

}

private class ClickListener implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        inhalt.setText(eingabe.getText());

    }



}

private class SchreibkopfListener implements CaretListener{

    @Override
    public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent arg0) {

        String inTextField = eingabe.getText();
        inTextField = inTextField.trim();
        if(inTextField.isEmpty()){
            button.setEnabled(false);
        }else{

            button.setEnabled(true);

        }



    }



}

private class FettListener implements ItemListener{

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {

        if(fett.isSelected()){

            Font font = inhalt.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 15);
            inhalt.setFont(font);

        }else{

            Font font = inhalt.getFont().deriveFont(Font.ITALIC, 15);
            inhalt.setFont(font);

        }


    }



}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Here's a wonderful lesson into why `null` layouts suck (and you should stop using them)

Let's just take a little look at these lines...

```
nhalt = new JLabel("TeXt");
inhalt.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 60);
inhalt.setToolTipText("Das ist ein Text");
//...
button = new JButton("HIER");
button.setBounds(100, 10, 100, 50);
```

So, the label starts at `0x0` and expands through `500x60`, okay, the button starts at `100x10` and expands through `100x50`, this means that the label and the button actually collide

Now, I know what you're thinking, but I add the button after the label, but this isn't how components actually get painted/respond to events.

Components are painted in reverse order of how they are added, this means that the label actually resides OVER the button (in terms of the Z-order), this also means that the label receives events BEFORE the button, this is important because...

```
inhalt.setToolTipText("Das ist ein Text");
```

installs a `MouseListener` on the `JLabel`, which consumes ALL mouse events, preventing the button from been notified.

So, long answer short, don't use `null` layouts (and take the time to better understand how the API actually works :P)